# How is $-16/4i$ equal to $4i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, rationalising-denominator

I came across a problem: $-16/4i$. Every time I put it into a calculator, it comes out as $4i$, but when I try to solve it is $-4i$, because of the negative one in front of the $16$.

Comment: Is it $-\cfrac{16}{4i}$ or $-\cfrac{16}4i$?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are entering the expression with or without parentheses?  And whether you are entering it all on one line, or as two separate calculations?  A lot depends on the details of how you are putting it into the calculator (see my answer and the discussion below it).

Comment: I cannot imagine why someone would vote to close this as not about math.  It is *clearly* appropriate for this site.

Comment: OP, I'm curious... are you using Matlab as your calculator? For some reason Matlab gives precedence to the imaginary unit $i$, unlike most handheld calculators like the TI-8x's, which apply the division symbol solely to the next number. @mweiss

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that you are entering $-16/4i$ into your calculator, but you *ought* to be entering $-16/(4i)$.  The calculator is (correctly) interpreting your input to mean $-16 \div 4 \times i$, which evaluated from left to right is in fact $-4i$.  If you want the calculator to compute $-16 \div (4 \times i)$, you need to include the parentheses.

And, as others have pointed out, dividing by $i$ is the same thing as multiplying by $-i$, because $\frac{1}{i} = -i$.

Comment: You have it backwards. The calculator is evaluating it to be $4i$, and OP is evaluating it to be $-4i$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger   Huh, I guess you are right. Strange, though -- how does one enter $-16/4i$ into a calculator and get $4i$ as a result unless one uses parentheses?

Comment: (I am assuming here that this is a graphing calculator that has a "complex numbers" mode -- otherwise I don't see how you can enter this into a calculator in the first place.)

Comment: My TI-83 evaluates the expression as $-4i$

Comment: @TheChaz2.0  Precisely my point.  If you enter $-16/4i$ into any calculator that will accept such an expression, it will give you $-4i$ as a result.  Yet the OP claims to be getting $4i$, which is the value of $-16/(4i)$. I wonder how?

Answer (score 4):

Notice, $i^2=-1$ hence, $$\frac{-16}{4i}=\frac{-16}{4i}\times\frac{i}{i}=\frac{-16i}{4i^2}=\frac{-16i}{4(-1)}=\frac{-16i}{-4}=\color{red}{4i}$$

Comment: Please stop editing the question; the original formatting is an important part of the content of the question, as indicated in mweiss's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What is $\frac{1}{i}$ equal to?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it:
$$
\frac{-16}{4i} = \frac{-16}{4i}\frac{-i}{-i} = \frac{16i}{4i(-i)} = \frac{16i}{4} = 4i.
$$
The key thing is that $i(-i) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it is:
$\frac{-16}{4i}$ Then reduce to get $\frac{-4}{i}$. We know that $i^2=-1$, there fore we can make it $\frac{4i^2}{i}$ and by reduceing again we get $4i$.

Comment: thanks, this is what my math teacher said

Comment: Your welcome. For me this is the most obvious way.